# How to integrate an installed application inside my app in a given view

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to open an installed application inside my app in a given view. Like I want to use a back button at top left corner and installed application should be loaded below the back button view. How can i implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly [link an app to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/android-launch-an-application-from-another-application). But you can't open an app inside another like a web view. You simply cannot.

Comment: Yeah it's true that you can't open app inside any app. That's not possible at all!